# Why did I receive myself as a quest reward?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

When I completed the quest "Find the missing Shipment" I was greeted by a strange reward screen that said "You Receive Tavros". Confusingly, Tavros is the name of the character I'm playing as. There was a button to show my inventory, but I couldn't tell if there was anything new in my inventory.

Why did the reward screen say I recieved my own character? Did I actually get anything from this quest?

[image: Quest reward screen]

Comment: Strange. The reward should be Harold the rare crossbow according to [wiki](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Find+the+Missing+Shipment). Have you got anything like that in your inventory?

Comment: I recall seeing this when I stole the reward ahead of time

Comment: Interesting bug. My theory is that the game recognizes if the quest reward is in a container, and substitutes the name of the reward with the name of the container. But player inventories are internally also handled as containers, so it substitutes the name of the character in that case.

Comment: And by the way, there are actually not one but *two* situations in  game where you indeed (in a way) receive "yourself" as a quest reward. Or rather an artistic representation of yourself. In act 3 there are opportunities to obtain both a statue of your character and a portrait of your character. The latter one is indeed a bit glitchy (it tends to show a different companion every time it loads), so that's what I actually expected this question to be about when I read the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the regular reward screen:

[image]

This screenshot was taken from [this video](https://youtu.be/LZOOcA1tuLU?feature=shared&t=100) by someone playing as *ColdBeer*.

So, **it's not so much that you have been rewarded yourself, but that the item(s) you should have been given are not displayed there**. Since that part of the pop-up is now missing, it reads `You Receive <(Active)PlayerName>`.

You should have been given the crossbow [Harold](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Harold) (as [Skye-AT points out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405090/why-did-i-receive-myself-as-a-quest-reward#comment568744_405090)).
If it's not in your inventory the gifting is bugged—if it is, the reward pop-up is bugged. Either way, you might want to [inform Larian about it](https://larian.com/support/baldur-s-gate-3#modal).

Comment: I found the crossbow Harold in my inventory, although I am unsure when I recieved it.

Comment: @Stevoisiak Probably at that time, as that makes the most sense. So it's purely a visual design bug. (Rereading my answer, with "the item(s) you should have been given are not there" I meant it in the sense of "displayed". I'll edit that in now to clarify..)